# Git : How to clone & get Specific folders only

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is it possible to Clone/download just the required specific folder from GIT repository instead of pulling the all the existing projects in the repo.

For Example .. Lets say

I have a repository named 'MyRepo' and i have added 2 Projects/Folders in this named 1)Java & (2) Python.

Now i have multiple small projects & assignments under Java & Python so the structure looks like this

- Java

  - CheckConcurrency
  - Billing System
  - DS

Similarly for Python as well...Now i have newly configured my laptop with Git so can i Just Pull Java projects only and start working in a specific directory on my machine & then later sometime later Pull only python projects into some other directory and just work on python..?

Reason i am asking for this is that i don't want unnecessary projects which i won't be touching to be into my working directory so i want to separate it out and just commit the specific project whenever i do any change..?

Comment: Then move the disparate files to separate repositories.  You could also use submodules here, but there are caviats with those and it might not even be necessary.  In general, Git is a _project_ based version control system.  You clone the entire repo at once.  This is different than some other _file_ based tools like Subversion etc. where you can checkout only files you want.

Comment: I don't want to create a Separate Repo

Comment: Sparse checkout can do half of what you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)